# VSCode Python Extension Commands Not Found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed VSCode and Python 3.6.4, and I was hoping to set up the Python extension for VSCode to enable linting, debugging, etc. Unfortunately, I'm not able to set up the extension correctly. The extension comes with a set of pre-loaded commands for the command palette. These include "Python: Create Terminal
", "Python: Select Interpreter", "Python: Enable Linting", among many others.

For some reason, whenever I try to run any of these commands, I receive a command not found error. For example, when I try running "Python: Create Terminal", I receive:

```
ERROR command 'python.createTerminal' not found
```

I have triple checked that the Python extension is installed and activated. I have not edited the User settings file with respect to the python extension at all. And I have already tried uninstalling the extension and reinstalling it.

To ensure that it's not a general problem with all of my extensions, I tried running a few ESLint commands and they all work fine. I've also ensured Python is on my path.

Any guidance for what else to try would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had the same issues with "[Python for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tht13.python)" plugin.
I have uninstalled it and I use "[Python extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)"
Pre-loaded commands for the command palette work fine now.

Comment: Now its just called "Python" (working) instead of "Python extension for Visual Studio Code" (not working).